# How to enable user to input multiple values (key value pairs) for a list item's field in listform

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, office-365, list-form, nintex

We have a list in SharePoint called Index requests. user submits a request to IT Team via this list for a new Index.

In the intake form user enters index name, department, type of index etc, plus we want the user to be able to input the fields they want to be created for that index with type eg. Name :Text, Dept:text, Point of Contact :User etc.

So for this, we need some repeating section kind of thing on the form with text boxes, just for this field and so that later I can grab the data and save it to list field. But How can I do that? Or is there a better way?

I did something like this in a nintex workflow earlier but I do not know how to accomplish this in a SharePoint form!

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar in a SP list form. I created a custom front-end for the form to allow the user to create "lines" for more key/value information (in my case it was "relevant procedures" which included a Title and a URL) which I then stored in a multi-line text field as HTML. Later when displaying the data on the edit form, I grabbed the value of the multi-line text field and parsed it back into the desired format. For the display, I was pulling back the data via REST, so I could simply plop the HTML on the page for a nice list display of relevant procedure links. I imagine something like this would work for your scenario as well.

Here's some sampling of my solution (attribute names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
//HTML on custom SP form
<div class='column-row'>
    <div class='column full'>
        <label class="relevant-procedures-label">
            Related Topics
            <div class="column-row relevant-procedures-head">
                <div class="column three-sevenths relevant-procedures">
                    <span>Title</span>
                </div>
                <div class="column three-sevenths relevant-procedures">
                    <span>URL</span>
                </div>
                <div class="column one-seventh relevant-procedures">
                    <span class="icon icon-plus add-relevant-procedure"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column-row relevant-procedures-row" id="relevant-procedures-row-1">
                <div class="column three-sevenths relevant-procedures">
                    <input type="text" class="relevant-procedure-title" />
                </div>
                <div class="column three-sevenths relevant-procedures">
                    <input type="text" class="relevant-procedure-url" />
                </div>
                <div class="column one-seventh relevant-procedures">
                    <span class="icon icon-cross remove-relevant-procedure"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="tsp-form" data-fin="RelevantProcedures" style="display: none;"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

// relevant procedures click handler (add row)
jQuery(".page-content").on("click", ".add-relevant-procedure", function () {
    var rowCount = jQuery(".relevant-procedures-row").length;
    var nextRowId = "relevant-procedures-row-" + (rowCount + 1);
    var newRow = jQuery("#relevant-procedures-row-1").clone().attr("id", nextRowId);
    newRow.find("input").val("");
    newRow.appendTo(".relevant-procedures-label");
});

// relevant procedures click handler (remove row)
jQuery(".page-content").on ("click", ".remove-relevant-procedure", function () {
    var thisRow = jQuery(this).closest(".relevant-procedures-row");
    if (thisRow.attr("id").slice(-1) == 1) {
        thisRow.find("input").val("");
    }
    else {
        thisRow.remove();
    }
});

// check/set relevant procedures on save (check if values and save to multi-line field as unordered list)
if (jQuery(".relevant-procedure-title").first().val()) {
    var relevantProcedures = '<ul>';
    jQuery(".relevant-procedures-row").each(function () {
        var title = jQuery(this).find(".relevant-procedure-title").val();
        var url = jQuery(this).find(".relevant-procedure-url").val();
        relevantProcedures += '<li><a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a></li>';
    });
    relevantProcedures += '</ul>';
    setVal("RelevantProcedures", relevantProcedures);
}

// create relevant procedures table (put stored HTML back in inputs for editform)
if (getVal("RelevantProcedures").indexOf('<li>') > -1) {
    getField("RelevantProcedures").find("li").each(function () {
        var title = jQuery(this).text();
        var url = jQuery(this).attr("href");
        var rowCount = jQuery(".relevant-procedures-row").length;
        var nextRowId = "relevant-procedures-row-" + (rowCount + 1);
        var newRow = jQuery("#relevant-procedures-row-1").clone().attr("id", nextRowId);
        newRow.find(".relevant-procedure-title").val(title);
        newRow.find(".relevant-procedure-url").val(url);
        newRow.appendTo(".relevant-procedures-label");
    });
}
```

There are some helper functions I've made which are used in the code sample (getVal, getField, etc.), so you will have to replicate the functionality manually or create your own helpers.

Here's how it looks on the form:

[image]

Here's how the display looks:

[image]

I hope this helps to give you an idea of how you can meet your requirements. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! In my requirement I too want to do the same thing that I could have 2 fields in a repeating section (or whatever you call it) and once user submits the form the repeating input field values can be consolidated in text/html form and inserted to a multi line column like you did. But, Can you please explain a bit more on exactly which files to modify and under which tags/element on the list form HTML the does the custom HTML go and where does the Jquery code be added. Much Thanks!

Comment: Actually I tried to replicate this by adding a CEWP on the new List form page and pointing it to a code file in Siteassets. Anyway, but I cannot make the code to work without the helper functions, unfortunately I am new with the javascript & jquery still learning. Can you please share the code for the functions?

Comment: Unfortunately my helper functions were designed for use with my custom front end, and will not work for you. They are basically switch functions, getVal("FieldName") retrieves the value of an input field and getField("FieldName") retrieves the input field element itself.